# ranking node based on traffic (incoming/outgoing)

Tags: algorithm, networking, social-networking

Am doing a research on traffic intersections in this research am trying to find  influential nodes , that is ... which intersections would influence each other , am trying to represent my network as a graph network , so i searched for algorithms already used in networks hoping to apply the same to my problem , what I came across was the PageRank algorithm but it seems that it only depends on the number of links , but in my case i want to take traffic into consideration too is there some algorithm out there that would help me achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

Some common algorithms to give 'importance' to nodes in a graph are [Pagerank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank), [HITS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HITS_algorithm) and [Salsa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SALSA_algorithm).

Pagerank is the most used and known from the mentioned algorithms.

Therse algorithms are originally designed to give importance to websites based on the links that reference them. Pagerank was developed by Larry Page and is considered as the early core of google's ranking.

Pagerank is conceptually a 'random surfer'. A surfer (car) starts at random web (junction), and has two choices: surf (move) to another webpage (junction), that is connected to the current webpage (junction), at probability `d`, or 'jump' to another webpage (junction) chosen at random from all the nodes in the graph at probability `1-d`. The pagerank score of a node at the end is the probability of this surfer to end up at this node. It seems fit to me for your case.

Comment: and how can i give importance in my case its (traffic flow) to some node ?

Comment: @fadytaher Pagerank is conceptually a 'random surfer'. A surfer (car) starts at random web (junction), and has two choices: move to another webpage (junction), that is connected to the current webpage (junction), at probability `d`, or 'jump' to another webpage (junction) chosen at random from all the nodes in the graph at probability `1-d`. The pagerank score of a node at the end is the probability of this surfer to end up at this node. It seems fit to me for your case.